# using RecyclerView in Android 4.3 not fixed size

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have read some tuts and info pages about the RecyclerView, so I've decided to do it, and as I followed those tuts finally I made it, but I have 1 question

- I have the RecyclerView in the xml layout,
- I coded a standard adapter for it (of course the one with RecyclerView.ViewHolder),
- I have a model class: List profiles, which has at least 1 item in it,
- I set up the LayoutManager (LinearLayoutManager),
- and added the DefaultAnimator....

This is the declared RView in  the xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/profiles_list"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"/>
```

As you can see it has a fixed height. But I'd like to achive not to have a fixed height, or it can have a maximum height, but till it reaches that size, should always be "wrap_content".

Items can be added and deleted from it --> so I thought **setHasFixedSize(false)** is good for things like this, and when it reaches the limit size it enables scrolling in it, if it is less than the given height, it shrinks its height to wrap content on deletion of items, and layout elements under this view snaps to it, of cource with animation.

is it only a dream (i mean this functionality already coded and out-of-the-box --> can be used...)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if its correct, but this help me. So just call after every adding or removing action

```
DefaultItemAnimator mItemAnimator = new DefaultItemAnimator();
mRecyclerView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

     @Override
     public void run() {
         mRecyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().clear();
         mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }

}, mItemAnimator.getRemoveDuration() + mItemAnimator.getMoveDuration());
```